# Keeping consistent scale_fill_gradient with trans log10 across 2 plots

Tags: ggplot2, maps, geom

I am having trouble getting the scale_fill_gradient I need with some maps I'm working with. What I'm looking for is 2 heatmaps that have the exact same color scale (like hex code corresponds to exact same fill value) with log10 transformation while the 2 datasets have different maxes.

This is what I have for a single heat map, and I like the result:

```
heatmap <- statebase +
  geom_sf(data=heatbycounties, color="NA", aes(fill=fy16map)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(trans="log10", low = "#F1EFEF", high = "#F25430", na.value = "#F1EFEF") + 
  geom_sf(data = c_states, color="white", fill="NA") + #adding white state lines back on top
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        rect = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill="white"))`\
```

But if I just produce two maps this way with the separate datasets (fy16map and fy22map) the "high" color corresponds to different values, and thus so does the entire gradient.

I've made various attempts with different combinations of arguments in scale_fill_gradient and scale_fill_gradientn but most resulted in error codes. I was able to generate one that had a defined color scale (assigned value for "low" and "high") but it was totally illegible without the log10 because the majority of the country is very low - it was just like a white map with a few orange spots.

Is it possible to both include the trans log10 *and* specify the min and max of the gradient? Surely this has a simple solution, but I'm new to R! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

You could try to set the limits for the the fill gradient as the minimum value in both datasets (maximum respectively), and use `oob = squish`from the `scales` package.
Note that you have to determine the min and max first, since I don't know what data you are using.

```
library(scales)

+ scale_fill_gradient(trans="log10", low = "#F1EFEF", high = "#F25430", na.value = "#F1EFEF", 
limits=c(min(log10(fy16map)), max(log10(fy16map)), oob=squish))
```

(Maybe) Solution 2:

You could also scale your matrices with `t(scale(t(mat)))`. If I remember correctly, this will transform your data to z values with a mean of 0 and a sd of 1, and therefore, to have the same limits.
I think it's generally good practice to show Row-z values in heatmaps.

Comment: I attempted solution 1 but it is still producing different color ranges (close, but not matching on the low end):
      scale_fill_gradient(trans="log10", low= "#FCF4C4", high= "#ED2C00", na.value = "#F1EFEF", limits=c(min(-1), max(log10(8200))), oob=squish)

I have tried for the min -1, 0.001, and 1 (true min of both is 0), same in both. For max I have tried 3500 (the fy16 max) and 8200 (the fy22 max) as well as log and log10 transformations of each in both (like 3500 in both, 3500 in 16 and 8200 in 22, and 8200 in both). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Also can you explain sol 2 more?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code?

Comment: Or this might be the solution: First, don’t hard Code the values (like min(-1). It doesn’t make sense).  The min function returns the lowest value in the data you provide. Same for max. Instead use min(your_data). To get both on the same scale, this should work now: limits = c(max(min(your_data1), min(your_data2)), min(max(your_data1), max(your_data2)))